# Finding the overlap of numpy images

Tags: python, numpy

If I have two numpy arrays:

```
a = np.array[[0,1,1],
             [0,1,0],
             [0,0,0]] 
b = np.array[[0,1,1],
             [0,0,1],
             [0,0,0]]
```

How could I find the 'overlap' between them, so the output is:

```
c =         [[0,1,1],
             [0,0,0],
             [0,0,0]]
```

I have this, but is there a way which could be quicker as my arrays are large?

```
c = a + b - 1
c[c<0] = 0
```

Comment: Hope the answer there helped

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If, as in your example, the values in the arrays are either 0 or 1, you can use the bitwise "and" operator `&`:

```
In [3]: a
Out[3]: 
array([[0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])

In [4]: b
Out[4]: 
array([[0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0]])

In [5]: c = a & b

In [6]: c
Out[6]: 
array([[0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: Thanks. It turns out that c = a==b is actually quite a bit faster!

Comment: @kezzos, is that the same result? c = a==b would return true if the values matched while c = a & b would give 1 wherever both were 1.